# Detect if credit card is from the US

Tags: php, security, woocommerce, e-commerce, fraud-prevention

I have a client with a WooCommerce site that is running into a scam that I can't find a quick solution for.

They are primarily a US based company, but the payment gateway is accepting credit cards that have been issued outside of the US.  The customer makes an order, completes the transaction, and then cancels the credit card. This is causing the client to be both out of money and product as the overseas banks typically don't care about refunding the money back to him.

What are some methods/strategies that I can use to make sure that all credit cards that come to his site are from the US?

Comment: Require a domestic billing address?

Comment: Alex, that's not going to work, as they have a US billing/shipping address, but their credit card comes from overseas.  I need to be able to check the credit card itself and where it's issued from before processing to validate it.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out:

https://binlist.net/

Now lets take a look on a credit card:

[image]

You can now use this and a custom WooCommerce filter to validate the BIN. You need to find a way getting the credit card number because I don't know which plugin you use for credit card payment:

```
/**
 * Check if credit card is from a us country
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'validate_credit_card', 10, 2 );
function validate( $data, $errors ) {
    $bin      = '45717360'; // <-- you need to find a way to get your credit card infos and take the first part with substr()
    $response = wp_safe_remote_get( 'https://lookup.binlist.net/' . $bin );

    if ( isset( $response['body'] ) ) {
        $response_body = json_decode( $response['body'] );

        if ( $response_body->country->alpha2 !== 'US' ) {
            $errors->add( 'credit_card_error', 'Your credit card is not from a US country.' );
        }
    } else {
        $errors->add( 'credit_card_error', 'Unable to check your credit card.' );
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked out in getting me to see the direction that I wanted to go.  I changed the action to 'woocommerce_before_checkout_validation' so that I don't waste resources on other verifications if the credit card isn't even valid.  Also, instead of an API, I was able to find an open source csv that I am doing a verification through.  Thank you for helping me get onto the right path.

Comment: @CadmusPaladin Awesome! That's another way to go. But keep in mind that your CSV will not be updated in case something changes.

Comment: True, for the interim it will do though.  It's a small client with not a lot of money, so going with an API service that has limits and possible costs in the future will help keep their business lean for now.  If something changes, then we can address it in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Do not allow orders if the credit card is issued outside of the US. Further you can also check geographic location based on the ip address of the request and restrict it to US only.